# фашист, бандит and their real equivalent meaning in Russian?

Tags: значения

While  фашист and бандит should translate in English respectively to 'fascist' and 'bandit', I have the feeling that their real meaning is much stronger in Russian than in English, indeed "you're a fascist" and "you're a bandit" sounds relatively low in English and these expressions are rather soft or even can be funny in English ( and in other languages ) while they are - I feel - much stronger in Russian ( or is that only Ukrainian ?). Is that impression correct or is that an illusion?

Comment: to most russians(and I mean almost everyone), фашист is a synonym of a "german nazi invader". I don't think I ever had a need to dig up the real meaning of this word prior to your question even though I knew it does not directly translates to the above.

Answer (score 12):

*Фашист* in colloquial Russian means primarily a German Nazi (or, through metonimy, any supporter of Nazi or Nazi-like ideology).

The term was widely used by the Soviet media in 1930's, and the German troops which invaded Soviet Union were labeled "German Fascist invaders" (*немецко-фашистские захватчики*) right away.

In stricter sense of word, it would mean quite the same as English "fascist".

Because of the cultural connotations, the term *фашист* would be deemed a very strong expression by majority of Russian speakers born or raised in the former USSR. I personally can't imagine a situation where it could be used jokingly.

*Бандит* means a "gangster", a member of an armed organized crime group. It's a legal term as well. Contrary to its English counterpart ("bandit"), it does not have positive connotations.

More correct translation of "bandit" to Russian would be *разбойник*. For instance, "good" guys like Robin Hood and Hong Gildong are usually called *разбойник*, but Al Capone or Tony Soprano would rather be *бандит*.

It's not quite a strong term, though. For instance, a mother could say *он такой бандит!* about her child, meaning the child does not behave.

Comment: I called one of my laika dogs 'бандит' and most people told me it was totally inappropriate for a dog ( anyway I saw some dogs have been named like that in the past as well, in USSR times )

Comment: @Karl: I personally see nothing wrong about naming a dog that.

Comment: A Ukrainian chiming in. Quassnoi indeed gave accurate enough explanation, "фашист" is a very serious accusation here as well. No local differences about "бандит" either, this is not a strong expression at all.

Comment: Revised comment: In 1930s Soviet propaganda branded various anticommunist movements (including fascists proper) as fascists, not specifically German Nazis. Since June 1941, certainly, *фашист* became to refer to the Third Reich and other Axis powers, and this meaning stuck to the word in popular usage.

Comment: >>>where it could be used jokingly  Well, I can. "Получи, фашист, гранату!" can well be used in a friendly banter especially when in conjunction with videogames.

Comment: @Zeks: you're right, that's one such usage.

Answer (score 2):

Well in Russian the term "fascist" is about as strong as the term "sadist". It in fact would mean "ethno-sadist" or "racial sadist" that is a person who enjoys to inflict suffering to other people for pleasure.